# function with name $

Tags: javascript, function

can someone explain how these three functions are related to each other?what function $ is doing here ? does it has two defintions ?

```
socket.onopen = function(){
    log("Welcome - status "+this.readyState); 
};

function $(id){ 
   return document.getElementById(id); 
}

function log(msg){ 
    $("log").innerHTML+="<br>"+msg; 
}
```

these functions are written a client code below:

var socket;

```
function init() {
    var host = "ws://localhost:12345/websocket/server.php";
    try {
        socket = new WebSocket(host);
        log('WebSocket - status ' + socket.readyState);
        socket.onopen = function (msg) {
            log("Welcome - status " + this.readyState);
        };
        socket.onmessage = function (msg) {
            log("Received: " + msg.data);
        };
        socket.onclose = function (msg) {
            log("Disconnected - status " + this.readyState);
        };
    } catch (ex) {
        log(ex);
    }
    $("msg").focus();
}

function send() {
    var txt, msg;
    txt = $("msg");
    msg = txt.value;
    if (!msg) {
        alert("Message can not be empty");
        return;
    }
    txt.value = "";
    txt.focus();
    try {
        socket.send(msg);
        log('Sent: ' + msg);
    } catch (ex) {
        log(ex);
    }
}

function quit() {
    log("Goodbye!");
    socket.close();
    socket = null;
} // Utilities  function $(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }  function log(msg){ $("log").innerHTML+="<br>"+msg; }  function onkey(event){ if(event.keyCode==13){ send(); } }
```

Answer (score 4):

The first function calls the third function. The third function calls the second function. There is no other relationship between them.

The `$` character has no special meaning in a variable name. You could use `foo` or `getEl` instead.

`$` is just a particularly uninformative name that has become popular for functions that get elements because it is (a) short and (b) is a character used in some other languages to indicate the start of a variable.

Answer (score 2):

It declares a function named `$` which take an id-string and returns the

```
documet.getEelementById(id);
```

Simple.

Answer (score 1):

The first function is an event handler. Whenever the object `socket` fires the `open` event, JavaScript will call the function defined in `socket.onopen`. This function will call another function named `log` defined below.

The second function creates a shorthand for `document.getElementById()`. Since the `$` character can be used as a regular identifier in JavaScript, it can be a handy tool for shortening common functions. The caveat here is that several common js libraries utilize that symbol for key functions, so you should probably avoid this in your custom code.

The `log` function uses the shorthand to select an element to receive the text of a message via concatenation. Whatever text is already there will have the message text added to it.

Answer (score 0):

Rewritten:

```
// Binds an anonymous function to the open event of the 
// object named socket. The handler function prints a
// status message in the log panel by invoking the 
// function defined below named log.

socket.onopen = function () {
    log("Welcome - status " + this.readyState); 
};

// Function named $ that returns the DOM element
// whose id attribute equals id.

function $(id) { 
    return document.getElementById(id); 
}

// Function named log that invokes the function named $.
//
// This function finds the DOM element whose id equals
// "log" and appends a line break and a message to its
// inner content.

function log(msg) { 
    $("log").innerHTML += "<br>" + msg; 
}
```